# Conditional return with Promises: throwing vs returning null

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm finding myself writing a lot of Promise code that handles cases where data may be unavailable, and I'm not sure whether to pass nulls or throw/catch in that case.

For example:

```
users.getById(id).then((user) => {
  if (!user) {
    return null;
  }
  return doSomething(user);
});
```

could be written as

```
users.getById(id).then((user) => {
  return doSomething(user);
}).catch((e) => {
  // User wasn't found
});
```

Are either of these generally preferable or idiomatic in some way, or is it best to follow my instincts in each case?

Comment: Second one looks more nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function is called `users.getById` then its callback should have a user object, period. The promise to get a user object is only fulfilled when you actually get a user object.

Throw [typed Error instances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Custom_Error_Types) to indicate various error conditions.

```
users.getById(id).then((user) => {
    return doSomething(user);
}).catch((e) => {
    switch (e.Name) {
        case "UserNotFound":
            // User wasn't found
            break;
        default:
            // unexpected error
    }
});
```

The `bluebird` promise library has [explicit support for typed exceptions](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html) and separate [support for catching operational errors](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error.html), you can mimic that behavior. Or you could just use bluebird:

```
users.getById(id).then((user) => {
    return doSomething(user);
}).error(UserNotFound, (e) => {
    // User wasn't found
}).catch((e) => {
    // unexpected error
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is an API call, typically, you want to save the throw part for the consumer, and not handle it internally.

...or handle the convert-to-JSON part internally, but if there are loading-errors, or conversion errors, let the outside world live with the oops.

Here's what I mean; we'll skip promises for a second:

```
function getData () {
  var data = null;
  try {
    data = getSomeData();
  } catch (e) { } // ignore it

  return data;
}


var data = getData();
var name = data.property.name; // BOOM
```

If it's going to throw, you should catch it (it would be better if it didn't throw, but better to know that it's going to throw, than not know).

```
function getData () {
  var data = getSomeData();
  return data;
}


var data;
var name;
try {
  data = getData();
  name = data.property.name;
} catch (e) { /* now at the right level */ }
```

Throwing in general is not great, of course. Nor is null, depending on your stance on functional programming.

If we made this a call that returned a promise:

```
function getData () {
  return callServer()
    .then( response => JSON.parse(response) );
}

getData()
  .then(showData)
  .catch(showError);
```

If that error was handled inside, it would never make it to the end-user to handle the fact that their stuff is missing. If you returned null, then they'd have to do all kinds of `null`-checks inside of their `then( )`.